# Python (Numpy) array sorting

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I've got this array, named v, of dtype('float64'):

```
array([[  9.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   3.45765000e+02],
       [  4.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.19200000e+00],
       [  1.33360000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.76650000e+02]])
```

... which I've acquired from a file by using the np.loadtxt command. I would like to sort it after the values of the first column, without mixing up the structure that keeps the numbers listed on the same line together. Using v.sort(axis=0) gives me:

```
array([[  1.33360000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.19200000e+00],
       [  4.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   3.45765000e+02],
       [  9.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.76650000e+02]])
```

... i.e. places the smallest number of the third column in the first line, etc. I would rather want something like this...

```
array([[  1.33360000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.76650000e+02],
       [  4.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   6.19200000e+00],
       [  9.33350000e+05,   8.75886500e+06,   3.45765000e+02]])
```

... where the elements of each line hasn't been moved relatively to each other.

Answer (score 13):

Try

```
v[v[:,0].argsort()]
```

(with `v` being the array).  `v[:,0]` is the first column, and `.argsort()` returns the indices that would sort the first column.  You then apply this ordering to the whole array using advanced indexing.  Note that you get a sorte copy of the array.

The only way I know of to sort the array in place is to use a record dtype:

```
v.dtype = [("x", float), ("y", float), ("z", float)]
v.shape = v.size
v.sort(order="x")
```

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively

Try

```
import numpy as np

order = v[:, 0].argsort()
sorted = np.take(v, order, 0)
```

'order' has the order of the first row.
and then 'np.take' take the columns their corresponding order.

See the help of 'np.take' as

```
help(np.take)
```

> take(a, indices, axis=None, out=None,
>   mode='raise')
>       Take elements from an array along an axis.
>
> ```
> This function does the same thing as "fancy" indexing (indexing arrays
> using arrays); however, it can be easier to use if you need elements
> along a given axis.
>
> Parameters
> ----------
> a : array_like
>     The source array.
> indices : array_like
>     The indices of the values to extract.
> axis : int, optional
>     The axis over which to select values. By default, the flattened
>     input array is used.
> out : ndarray, optional
>     If provided, the result will be placed in this array. It should
>     be of the appropriate shape and dtype.
> mode : {'raise', 'wrap', 'clip'}, optional
>     Specifies how out-of-bounds indices will behave.
>
>     * 'raise' -- raise an error (default)
>     * 'wrap' -- wrap around
>     * 'clip' -- clip to the range
>
>     'clip' mode means that all indices that are too large are
> ```
>
> replaced
>           by the index that addresses the last element along that axis. Note
>           that this disables indexing with negative numbers.
>
> ```
> Returns
> -------
> subarray : ndarray
>     The returned array has the same type as `a`.
>
> See Also
> --------
> ndarray.take : equivalent method
>
> Examples
> --------
> >>> a = [4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8]
> >>> indices = [0, 1, 4]
> >>> np.take(a, indices)
> array([4, 3, 6])
>
> In this example if `a` is an ndarray, "fancy" indexing can be used.
>
> >>> a = np.array(a)
> >>> a[indices]
> array([4, 3, 6])
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you have instances where `v[:,0]` has some identical values and you want to secondarily sort on columns 1, 2, etc..,  then you'll want to use [`numpy.lexsort()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) or [`numpy.sort(v, order=('col1', 'col2', etc..)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) but for the `order=` case, `v` will need to be a structured array.

Answer (score 0):

An example application of `numpy.lexsort()` to sort the rows of an array and deals with ties in the first column. Note that `lexsort` effectively sorts columns and starts with the last column, so you need to reverse the rows of `a` then take the transpose before the `lexsort`, and finally transpose the result (you'd have thought this should be easier, but hey!):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[1,0,4,1],[0,4,1,1]])

In [3]: a[np.lexsort(np.flip(a, axis=1).T).T]
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 4, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 4, 1],
       [1, 2, 3, 4]])

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 0, 4, 1],
       [0, 4, 1, 1]])
```

Thanks go to @Paul for the suggestion to use `lexsort`.